# Adding Loaded Event Handler

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to make a window to slide up from the bottom of the screen when it opens. However im having an issue with my code, im getting the following error when adding my Method to the Loaded event

Error:

> Additional information: Value cannot be null.

This is the code which adds the Method to the Eventhandler, and the Method:

```
//Position the Notification
            var workingArea = SystemParameters.WorkArea;
            this.Left = (workingArea.Width - this.ActualWidth) / 2;

            //Create storyboard for animation
            Loaded += animate;
        }
    }            
}

public RoutedEventHandler animate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var workingArea = SystemParameters.WorkArea;

    Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
    var slide = new DoubleAnimation()
    {
        BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
        Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
        By = -100
    };
    Storyboard.SetTarget(slide,this);
    Storyboard.SetTargetName(this, "MyWindow");
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(slide,new PropertyPath("(Window.Top)"));

    this.Top = workingArea.Height - this.ActualHeight;
    return null;
}
```

**Edit:**
This is the entire Window Code Behind, which should handle the animations and positioning.

```
 /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for NotificationAll.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class NotificationAll : Window
    {
        public NotificationAll() : base()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        public new void Show()
        {
            //Ensure new notifications are placed above older ones
            if (!Application.Current.Windows.Cast<Window>().Where(x =>
            x != this).Any(x => x.GetType().Name == "NotificationAll"))
            {
                this.Topmost = true;
                base.Show();

                this.Owner = System.Windows.Application.Current.MainWindow;

                //Position the Notification
                var workingArea = SystemParameters.WorkArea;
                this.Left = (workingArea.Width - this.ActualWidth) / 2;

                //Create storyboard for animation
                Loaded += SlideFromBottom;
            }
        }

        public void SlideFromBottom(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("h");
            var workingArea = SystemParameters.WorkArea;

            Storyboard sb = new Storyboard();
            var slide = new DoubleAnimation()
            {
                BeginTime = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(2),
                Duration = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1),
                By = -100
            };
            Storyboard.SetTarget(slide,this);
            Storyboard.SetTargetName(this, "MyWindow");
            Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(slide,new PropertyPath("(Window.Top)"));

            this.Top = workingArea.Height - this.ActualHeight;
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Close window once animation is complete
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="sender"></param>
        /// <param name="e"></param>
        private void DoubleAnimationCompleted(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsMouseOver)
            {
                this.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: The debugger must be pointing it to a line. What was that line?

Comment: @EmpereurAiman Updated Post since, got different error now

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's pretty simple. You are calling your `animate` method and assigning the result of it to the `Loaded` event. The `animate` method always returns null in your case. If you want `animate` to be an event handler, you should not call it using the parenthesis. You should instead do `Loaded += animate;`
And it should have the correct signature: `void animate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`

Comment: And it should have the correct signature `void animate(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)`

Comment: Yes, forgot about it :)

Comment: Or use a lambda expression: `Loaded += (o, e) => animate();`

Comment: Just made these changes, but not it doesn't seem to be firing at all. I placed a `MessageBox` before any other code in the `animate` method, and it does not get displayed :S

Comment: Are you subscribing to Loaded event from the constructor or some other method? Do you have a Loaded event handler specified from the XAML?

Comment: @EmpereurAiman Im subscribing to it like seen in the code in my post.

Comment: That shows part of a function. If it's not in the constructor, or any other evnet before window "Loads" it won't work.

Comment: P.S please don't edit your original question. It makes the answers outdated. Just add an "Edit:" and say what changed.

Comment: @EmpereurAiman I have added the entire window Code behind, if this helps

Comment: Did you try calling `Show` method from constructor?

Comment: Would it be easier to do what i'm attempting using XAML in the `Window.Triggers`, I would prefer to do it that way instead of all of this code-behind but I was having issues with the TargetProperty, as I couldn't Target the Window or find a way to make it slide up from the bottom of the Window